# Classic ASP upload - free or commercial components?

Tags: windows, upload, asp-classic

My ASP uploading of files knowledge is somewhere circa 2002. I've got a Classic site running in 32-bit mode on a 64-but Windows 2003 server. Also testing on a 32-bit Win 7 box.

What are a couple of upload solutions that might work in this scenario? I am running Classic ASP 3.0 against a SQL Server 2005 database. I prefer to store the files outside of the database.

I also have .NET 3.5 on the box, so if there's a hybrid solution that might work better, I can do that.

I'm mostly concerned that I'll use something "old" and that it won't be reliable.

I'd also like to run some sort of antivirus against the files when they come in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any components to upload using VBScript:

[File Upload using a VBScript Class - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/vbsupload.aspx)

I've used this on all Classic ASP sites migrated to 2008 RB 64-Bit servers and found it (nearly) slots right in your code with very little modifications.  Additionally, the very few components are 64-bit compatible and/or cause the application pools to crash after only modest use.

RE virus scanning, as long as your system has an A/V solution with real-time protection you are covered.  Otherwise you will need to use shell.execute to call the AV scanner on your newly uploaded file:

```
'Create new instance of the vbsUpload object'
set objUpload = new vbsUpload

'Generate the full path to save the file to'
strNewFileName = Server.MapPath("/uploads") & "\" & objUpload.files.Item(0).FileName

'Save the file to disk'
objUpload.Files.Item(0).Save strNewFileName
Set objUpload = Nothing

'File is now saved, run a/v scanner on it'
Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

'Run the scanner on the filename created above'
Set objCmd = objWShell.Exec("c:\myscanner\scan.exe -parameters " & strNewFileName) 

'Get the stdout from the process'
strOutput = objCmd.StdOut.Readall() 
Set objCmd = Nothing
Set objWShell = Nothing
```

Setting permissions on all this is "interesting" to say the least, but that should get you started.

Comment: I could use some guidance, yeah. And how to send notification back to the page.

Comment: Added example of calling a process with Shell.exec

Comment: @abatishchev What was the purpose of your edit? That's not how comments in VBScript work.

Comment: There is well-known issue in code highlighter used on SO, that VB comments not ended with ' are not parsed properly

Answer (score 0):

I used to work for a company (SoftArtisans) that sold an upload product for ASP, FileUp.  It's still fully supported, if you're willing to pay for a good solution, and I can attest to its reliability.  It's a COM component with an available .NET wrapper, so you could use it in either solution:

Here's a link to some evals:

http://fileup.softartisans.com/

I don't know all of the competitors, but I believe there is an API called ABCUpload.  I do not know who sells it.

You could also upload natively in .NET using the HttpPostedFile class.  There are a few tutorials you can find online.  Here's a link to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A free, well supported, component is [Pure ASPUpload](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pure-asp-upload.htm) but this has a 10mb file size limit. Ok if you don't need to upload files larger than this. If you do they have a paid for version.